# Remove part number from description of purchase.order.line

Tags: odoo-13

We are using odoo v13 and would like to make some changes to the PO report. Currently, the PO lines all have the part number in square brackets at the beginning of the description. We want to separate the PN and the description so that we can show our internal PN next to any vendor PNs:
[image]

As you can see, `TBL101` is the vendor code, `FURN_6741` is the internal PN. But the vendor code (in this case internal PN because of us trying various things) shows up in the description as well.

Using anything other than the purchase_order.line.name (description field) won't work because sometimes we edit the description to add more context and we need that to appear on the PDF report.

Is there any way to remove the internal/vendor PN from the beginning of the description on SO lines?

Answer (score 0):

Yes remove them from **the Qweb of the report**, you remove `FURN_6741` from the Qweb in the `t-field`.

Comment: Sorry but this is incorrect. In the QWEB report, the description is `<span t-field="line.description"/>`. It is the `description` field of the `purchase.order.line` model that is a string with the PN and the description...

Comment: Okay then redefine the description field in the inherited model of the `purchase.order.line`, it must have a `default=` or a `compute=` function. modify it in such a way that `FURN_6741` is no longer part of the calculation. would be helpful if more context was provided

Comment: Did you solve this?